# Search, count and add - Python

Tags: python, css, search, count, indexing

```
properties = ["color", "font-size", "font-family", "width", "height"]


inPath = "style.css"
outPath = "output.txt"

#Open a file for reading
file = open(inPath, 'rU')
if file:
    # read from the file
    filecontents = file.read()
    file.close()
else:
    print "Error Opening File."

#Open a file for writing
file = open(outPath, 'wb')
if file:
    for i in properties:
        search = i
        index = filecontents.find(search)   
        file.write(str(index), "\n")
    file.close()
else:
    print "Error Opening File."
```

seems to work, but:

- It only searches a keyword once?
- Its not writing to the output file. `function takes exactly 1 argument`
- I don't want it to print the index actually, but the number of time the keyword appears.

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you want `.count(search)`, not `.find(search)`, if what you're looking for is # of occurrences.

Second, `.write()` only takes a single parameter - if you want to write a newline, you need to concatenate it first, or call `.write()` twice.

Third, doing `for i in properties: search = i` is redundant; just use the name you want in your for loop.

```
for search in properties:
    cnt = filecontents.count(search)
    file.write(str(cnt) + "\n")
```

Comment: splendid! thanks heaps. just one question. will it add count if found "the" in "then" for example?

Comment: Yes. If you want to only match full words, you'd probably need to use a regex instead, or `.split()` the string and match individual tokens for equality.

Comment: So it would count "color" twice, once for "color" and also for "background-color"? Ah!

Comment: @Nimbuz: Fourth, The error handling with `if file` is ineffective.  The built-in `open()` will raise an exception if opening the file failed.  Use `try`/`except` instead.

Comment: the standard way to write in a file is `print >>file,cnt` on python 2.X and print(cnt,file=file) in python 3.X

Comment: ok, I'm trying this `re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(property), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search` to find full words, but it returns an object instead of string or count.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import imap
properties = ("color", "font-size", "font-family", "width", "height")


inPath = "style.css"
outPath = "output.txt"

try:
    #Open a file for reading
    filecontents = file(inPath).read()
except Exception as exc:
    print exc
else:
    #Open a file for writing
    with open(outPath, 'wb') as out_file:
        #for property in properties:
        #    out_string = "%s %s\n"   
        #    out_file.write( out_string % (
        #                      property, filecontents.count(property)))
        outfile.write('\n'.join(
                      imap(str, imap(filecontents.count, properties))))
```